# How to send array data via $http POST and Parse the same in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, angularjs, json

```
var send=[];

// send[] data contains:
// [{"host":"1","name":"2","password":"3"},
//  {"host":"4","name":"5","password":"6"},
//  {"host":"7","name":"8","password":"9"},
//  {"host":"10","name":"11","password":"12"}]

$http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'file.php',
        data: send,
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'Content-type: application/json'
        },

      }).
      success(function(response) {}).
      error(function(response) {});

      return false;
    };
```

I'm getting errors when I send the data, and I'm not able to parse this data using $_POST. I've tried doing the following:

```
var obj=(JSON.stringify(send));
data:obj,
```

and in my PHP file:

```
$request = file_get_contents('php://input');
                 $data=json_decode($request);
                 print_r($data);
```

Comment: what errors are you getting? (It's enough to have `$http.post("file.php", send).then(function(response){ ... })`)  You can try returning the data with `echo json_encode($data)` too

Comment: From localhost: <br /> <b>Notice</b>: Undefined index: name in <b>/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/try/parse.php</b> on line <b>2</b><br /> <br /> <b>Notice</b>: Undefined index: password in <b>/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/try/parse.php</b> on line <b>3</b><br /> <br /> –

Comment: thats the response i get, when i do<br> success(function(response) { window.alert(response);

Comment: are you using Mac? Shouldn't you be using [MAMP](https://www.mamp.info/en/) local server instead of XAMPP? But it's definitely a back-end issue

Comment: Does your code work if you change `'Content-Type': 'Content-type: application/json'` to `'Content-Type': 'application/json'`

Comment: I shall check it out and post the result

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retreive data that was posted, use `$_POST['data']`:

```
$request = $_POST['data'];
$data = json_decode($request);
print_r($data);
```

Could you elaborate what you mean by "I'm getting errors"?

Comment: From localhost: <br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: name in <b>/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/try/parse.php</b> on line <b>2</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: password in <b>/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/try/parse.php</b> on line <b>3</b><br />
<br />

Comment: thats the response i get, when i do<br>   success(function(response) {
      window.alert(response);

Comment: show your posted data, you can do so by `print_r $_POST['data']; exit;` and see ajax response,

Comment: I did not downvote but it is wrong. Nowhere in the JavaScript code it uses a "post variable" called `data`.

Comment: AngularJS-> $http({
        method: method,
        url: url,
        data: FormData,
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        },